# Discord.net how to process Auditlog.data

Tags: discord.net

I am currently working on a bot command, that is supposed to checks if a user has role "foobar". If so i want to read the audit log when he was assigned that role. i can fetch the audit log and read the result etc, but i cant process the data. I have tried many different ways, but every time i end up with audit.data.Equals,  .GetHashCode, .GetType or .ToString.

I tried to parse audit.data via a foreach but that doesnt work either since .data doesnt have a GetEnumerator instance.

```
    public async Task GetUsers()
    {
        var userlist = Context.Guild.Users;
        
        var channellist = Context.Guild.Channels;
        foreach(var s in userlist)
        {
            if (!(s.IsBot))
            {
                foreach (var userrole in s.Roles)
                {
                    if (userrole.ToString() == "foobar")
                    {
                        var auditlogs = Context.Guild.GetAuditLogsAsync(10, null, null, s.Id, ActionType.MemberRoleUpdated).FlattenAsync();
                        foreach (var audit in auditlogs.Result)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(audit.Data.GetType());
                            IAuditLogData auditdata = audit.Data;
                            foreach (var datalog in audit.Data)
                            {


                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad way to go about doing this. The audit logs don't stay around forever, and because you're only fetching 10 in this case it's likely that the event won't be found. You'd be better off listening to the GuildMemberUpdated event and storing the time that they were given a role in a database.

Comment: thank you for your feedback :D the audit logs are retrieved for each user individually that's why it is currently only set to 10. i am working with test environment not the acutall server yet. the live server allready has a lot of users with the role. that's why we do want to have a bot. the role is assigned manually. would it be feasible to just go by memberjoin date for this case and store new members in a database afterwards?

Comment: Yes that would be best I think. Audit logs don't stay around forever anyway, on my server I can only go back a few months

Comment: thx alot :D that really helped me out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly read IAuditLogData, as it is an interface for all the different audit log data types. You need to cast it first, then you can use it.
Something like this should work:

```cs
foreach (var audit in auditlogs.Result)
{
    if (audit.Data is MemberRoleAuditLogData data)
    {
        // use the "data" variable here
    }
}
```

However, as mentioned in the comments audit log data doesn't stick around forever, and you'd be better off using events and storing this information in a database. Also, you cannot search by who was updated, your example searches for who did the updating (sounds like a bot in your case). You would need to add another filter for `data.Target`.